# How do I do a case statement in MySQL with insert and update?

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I need to update information on table "consumers" with data from "participant_search", and if the row doesn't already exist, I need to insert.  One would think an "insert... on duplicate key update" however the key is an auto increment as every other column is not required to be unique.  The uniqueness comes from a combination of a few columns.  Apparently "If Exists" is not able to be used in MySQL (only MSSQL).  Anyway, here is my code.  The error is "... for the right syntax near 'CASE WHEN...'  Thank you for your guidance in advance.

```
SELECT * FROM consumers 
  CASE 
    WHEN tenantid = 'tenant1' and DOB = '1970-01-01' and nameLast = 'Johnson' and ptID = '123456' 
      THEN UPDATE consumers ptID=p.ID, tenantid=p.tenantid, NameLast=p.LastName, NameFirst=p.FirstName, 
        Address1=p.Address1, Address2=p.Address2, City=p.City, State=p.State, Zip=p.Zip, County=p.County, 
        DOB=p.DateofBirth 
      ELSE INSERT INTO consumers (ptID, tenantid, NameLast, NameFirst, Address1, Address2, City, State, 
        Zip, County, DOB) select p.ID, p.tenantid, p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.Address1, p.Address2, 
        p.City, p.State, p.Zip, p.County, p.DateofBirth 
  END 
INNER JOIN participant_search p;
```

Comment: Take a look at [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You can use a `SELECT` as the source for an insert. No need for the `CASE` statement. Just create a unique key on the columns that make the row unique. If you need to check for certain values in those columns, do that in the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT`.

Comment: If that isn't clear, edit your question and show a few source data rows, and the expected results from those rows (as text, not an image), and I'll try to write the query.

Comment: The problem with unique columns is that the uniqueness is from a combination of rows.  For example: 
ID - tenantid - DOB - nameLast - ptID
1  -  tenant1 - 1970-01-01 - Jones - 123456
2  -  tenant2 - 1970-01-01 - Smith - 987654
3  -  tenant1 - 1972-12-31 - Doe - 456789
4  -  tenant2 -  1970-01-01 - Jones - 123456
Notice that row 1 and 4 are the same (except for the tenantid).  It would need to recognize the combination of all 4 to determine whether it exists (to update) or not (to insert). I have used on duplicate key in the past, but it was much more clear what was unique there.

Comment: That's why you create a single unique index on those columns, all of them in a single index. That way the row is only unique if all of the columns match.

Comment: Also, see my second comment above - rather than putting an example in a comment, edit your question and put it there. An alternative is to use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to create an example with data (not all, just a sample). It also makes a great copy/paste text with table create statements and sample data you can paste directly into a SO question.

Comment: Sloan, your comment of doing a "single unique on those columns" was the key (pardon the pun).  I did not realize I could do that.  That fixed it.  Thank you very much!